# Can you update from Ubuntu 12.04.1 to 14.04.1 on powerpc?

Tags: 14.04, powerpc

I have an iBook G4 that has Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) installed on it. Update Manager says there i can update to 14.04.1 LTS, and I would like to know whether or not I can update without any serious problems involved.

Answer (score 0):

Under most circumstances you can complete this without any problems, although problems can occur and it is recommended that you backup you hard drive before doing the backup.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response! I'll try that right now.

Comment: If this help you in any way please push the up arrow, if you come back tomorrow and my answer is still the best please push the check mark beside my answer, this will help me to continue answering your questions quickly.

Comment: The update failed because it couldn't download the necessary file. I'll try it again and post some more details if it fails again.